# Batch - call another batch and have it executed

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to get some batch files working.

The first one I have (which works) takes a `.rar` from one drive to another and give the dir same name as the files put to rar and then copy a rename.bat file to the destination.

```
@ECHO OFF
cd /d J:\xxx
set path=C:\Program Files\WinRAR
FOR /f "delims=" %%d IN ('DIR /B') DO md J:\xxx\%%~nd
FOR /f "delims=" %%d IN ('DIR /B') DO WinRAR a -m0 -ep -vn -v500000B "xxx\%%~nd\%%~nd.rar" "%%~fd"
cd /d J:\xxx
FOR /f "delims=" %%d IN ('DIR /B') DO copy J:\xxx\rename.bat J:\xxx\%%~nxd 
EXIT
```

The second calls the rename.bat and executes it, but only partially works as it calls the rename.bat but does not execute only open up a new window.

```
@ECHO OFF
cd /d J:\xxx
for /f "delims=" %%n IN ('DIR /B') DO start J:\xxx\%%~n\rename.bat
EXIT
```

and the rename.bat looks like this:

```
for /f "Tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /l/b/a-d') do (rename "%%f" "%%f")
```

This one work if I just execute the files in the dir, but it would not work when called.

Anyone have any idea to make this happen as I'm lost for good ideas for now.

If it could be done in a single .bat I would love that too.

Comment: Instead of 
`for /f "delims=" %%n IN ('DIR /B') DO start J:\xxx\%%~n\rename.bat`
in the second batch file, have you tried
`for /f "delims=" %%n IN ('DIR /B') DO cmd \c J:\xxx\%%~n\rename.bat`
Also, remember that if the path to `J:\xxx\%%~n\rename.bat` has any spaces in it, then Command Prompt will only process it up to the space and thus not work.

Comment: If i use for /f "delims=" %%n IN ('DIR /B') DO cmd \c J:\xxx\%%~n\rename.bat then it only opens up a cmd and stands in the J:\xxx dir and nothing more happens.

Comment: What do you expect `do (rename "%%f" "%%f")` to do anyway? It seems to be renaming to the name it already had ...

Answer (score 2):

`CALL BATCHFILE2.BAT` will do precisely what you want, as explained in

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103994/how-to-run-multiple-bat-files-within-a-bat-file

`COMMAND /C BATCHFILE2.BAT` would also work, with drawbacks of possible added memory consumption, as per http://support.microsoft.com/kb/34768

Comment: if i do the CALL then it processes the directorys where there are no rename.bat in, and says J:\xxx\zzz\rename.bat is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. and do not run through the other dirs where the rename.bat are in or at least it might run through them but change nothing and give no sign inthe cmd that it do.